# Mark all emails read in specified folder

Tags: vba, outlook

I have an Outlook 2019 IMAP account and I'm trying to use the following VBA code to mark all emails in the "Spam" folder as read automatically.

I found code here on Stack Overflow and changed first IF statement to get only the Spam folder.

It gives me

> "Array index out of bounds"_ error (80020009)

after 3rd or 4th iteration (so up to three emails are being deleted) and the code breaks.

Why is it failing, and can I parameterize this code to choose an arbitrary folder name?

```
    Sub MarkAllItemsAsRead()
    Dim objStores As Outlook.Stores
    Dim objStore As Outlook.Store
    Dim objOutlookFile As Outlook.Folder
    Dim objFolder As Outlook.Folder

    'Process all Outlook files
    Set objStores = Outlook.Application.Session.Stores

    For Each objStore In objStores
        Set objOutlookFile = objStore.GetRootFolder

        For Each objFolder In objOutlookFile.Folders
            'Process mail folders
            If objFolder.DefaultItemType = olMailItem And objFolder.Name = "Spam" Then
                Debug.Print objFolder.Name
                Call ProcessFolders(objFolder)
            End If
        Next
    Next
    End Sub

    Sub ProcessFolders(ByVal objCurFolder As Outlook.Folder)
    Dim objUnreadItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim objSubFolder As Outlook.Folder

    Set objUnreadItems = objCurFolder.Items.Restrict("[Unread]=True")

    'Mark all unread emails as read
    For i = 1 To objUnreadItems.Count
        Set objItem = objUnreadItems.Item(i)
        objItem.UnRead = False
        objItem.Save
    Next

    End Sub
```

Comment: What's your code? What have you tried, and what's the problem? Keep in mind that "will someone please write code for me" is not an approach that'll win you many friends here.

Comment: I'm so sorry, here it is but after 3 iteration it gives me "Array index out of bound" error (80020009):

Answer (score 0):

Simply reversing the order of iteration will likely fix your problem.

What's (probably) happening here is that when you change the messages, the server wants to be extra helpful, and moves them messages elsewhere, and once that is done, what was "message number 2" is now "message number 1". Processing them starting with the highest number ought to solve it, because if the highest-numbered message goes away, no other messages are renumbered.

IMAP offers better ways to solve it (either setting all read with one command, or specifying them by UID instead of by sequence number), but reversing the order of iteration is a small change and probably will work.

Comment: Ok, I've got it now, thanks a lot. 

Could you please also tell me why in this code there is _objItem.Save_? What do I save there?